# Nested entities in Grails with HAL renderer

Tags: grails

I've got grails domain class that looks like this

```
class Thing {
  String name
  static hasMany = [
    variants: Variant
  ]
}
```

and another one like this

```
class Variant {
  String name
  static belongsTo = [
    thing: Thing
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the hal renderer to do a deep rendering.

Is that possible? How should I achieve it?

Comment: I wish I had the answer, because I have been wondering the same thing.  I have been messing around with extending HalJsonRenderer and HalJsonCollectionRenderer, and hypothetically I could use some Reflection to pick out the lists and then render them.  Honestly thought I want to render a child collection as a url.  Like if I am getting the comments on a blog it would just return a link like blog/1/comments.

Comment: Something new about this? ... im in same situation and cannot figure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, it seems a known bug in grails (https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10954)

There is a (not very nice) workaround,

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class ProductController extends RestfulController  {
    def halPCollectionRenderer
    def halPRenderer

    static responseFormats = ['hal','json']

    ProductController() {
        super(Product)
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        halPCollectionRenderer.mappingContext = mappingContext
        halPRenderer.mappingContext = mappingContext
    }

    MappingContext getMappingContext() {
        final context = new KeyValueMappingContext("")
        context.addPersistentEntity(Product)
        context.addPersistentEntity(Category)
        return context
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.